# Rails 3 UJS - on hover, not on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ujs

For my show action, I render show.js.erb. This happens when I click a link_to set up with a `:remote => true` option. How can I set it up so this is triggered on hover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a link with an attribute that won't trigger the Rails-UJS driver:

```
<%= link_to 'mouse over me!', '#', :'data-remote-on-hover' => true %>
```

and then wireup your own event:

```
$('a[data-remote-on-hover]').hover(function() {
  // do something
})
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 custom data attributes FTW!

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes